# asp core - passing data to main layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I wanna pass some data from the database to the main layout, I made a partial view called `_Nav`

```
@model IEnumerable<cms.Models.Page>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.Title
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

It lives inside `views/home`

And in the `HomeController` I have the following method which returns the partial view:

```
public IActionResult Pages()
        {
            return PartialView("_Nav", _context.Pages.ToList());
        }
```

But how do I display it in the main layout file (I think `@Html.Action` was used in mvc 5 for that) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a view component for rendering the menu.

```
public class MenuViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;

    public MenuViewComponent(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context= context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var items = await db.Pages.ToListAsync();
        return View(items);
    }        
}
```

And create a corresponding razor view for your view component called `Default.cshtml` inside `~/Shared/Components/Menu` directory. You can use your existing view code there.

```
@model List<Pages>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.Title
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Now you can invoke this view component in your layout

```
<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("Menu")
</div>
```

You may also invoke this view component with the tag helper style syntax. First add your `~\Views\_ViewImports.cshtml` file to call `addTagHelper` method with your assembly name so that our custom tag helpers can be used across the project.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, YourProjectsAssemblyName
```

Now in the layout,

```
<vc:menu ></vc:menu>
```

Comment: I put the class in the controllers folder, should it go to a better place as per best practice? Should I create a viewcomponents folder or something similar?

Comment: That is a subjective question. I personally keep all these inside a folder called `Infrastructure/Components`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code inside the views/home/index.cshtml file:

```
@Html.Action("Pages", "Home")
```

This will call your Pages method which will render and return the HTML into your view. You are on the right track, but putting this inside the views/home/index.cshtml file will help keep your project more organized.